# PowerShell script does not run program using UNC paths or mapped drive when running from windows 2016 task scheduler

Tags: windows-server-2016, scheduled-task

I am running powershell scripts from the Windows 2016 task scheduler that execute a program using either UNC paths or a drive mapped in the script.

Both variants run fine in powershell but do not work when run from the task.

I know the scripts are executing because of the messages in the mapped drive variant.

I am running powershell on the server using the same user account used in the task.

The application requires DLLs that are located in the ..\runtime folder shown in the scripts.

The UNC script is:

$Env:Path+=";\\myserver\apps\runtime

\\myserver\apps\myapp.exe

This just fails silently.

The mapped drive script is:

If (!(Test-Path X:))

{

```
  New-PSDrive -Name X -PSProvider FileSystem –Root "\\myserver\apps"
```

}

$Env:Path+= ";X:\runtime"

X:\myapp.exe

This version generates warnings in the powershell event log of "Provider Health: Could not find the drive 'X:\'. The drive might not be ready or might not be mapped." for both lines where the X: drive location is referenced

Comment: What permissions are you running it under in the task scheduler?  How did you create the task?  Some methods of creating a task will result in tasks that can only access local resources.

Comment: By permissions in the task scheduler to you mean the account the task is run under? It is an account with local admin privileges and full permissions for the path. I created the task manually in task scheduler. I tried both a "regular" task and a basic task.

Comment: Just to provide more details on the permissions - I have a domain user myuser. They have local admin rights on the server running powershell and task scheduler. \\myserver\data is a share that gives full access to Everyone. This is a share for the c:\data folder on myserver. myuser has full permissions on c:\data and permissions are set to propagate to subfolders and files. I also forced a new propagation. myuser is set as the account for the task in task scheduler and is the account I log into the server with to test running from powershell.

Comment: Well, this turned out to be major user error. In the task General tab under Run whether user is logged in or not the Do not store password option was checked. This explicitly says that the task will only have access to local resource if this is checked. When I uncheck this and set the task up to run \\myserver\apps\myapp.exe and starting in \\myserver\apps\runtime\ it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this turned out to be major user error. In the task General tab under Run whether user is logged in or not the Do not store password option was checked. This explicitly says that the task will only have access to local resource if this is checked. When I uncheck this and set the task up to run \myserver\apps\myapp.exe and starting in \myserver\apps\runtime\ it works as expected.